# What is the best way to returning client logs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

We have a healthcare system am working on in PHP and MySQL and each patient has a unique identifier which is used the next time they return. We want the system to be able to log each time a patient returns. We are faced with two options of doing this
1. Create a new log(mysql row) each time they came back.
2. or create a field with the number of times they return and we just keep incrementing the value for each visit i.e $returns++.

What is the best way we can implement this for the best performance, scalability and to also provide accurate analytics because this data is later exported to Microsoft Power BI, Excel and SPSS.

We want to be able to show the number of times each user returns and we expect about 250,000 - 500,000 patient visits per year.

Comment: Separate rows, with rotating of blocks of dates.  It depends if the date from the previous visit is important, and how long you need to track that for.  The flaw in just increment a value, is you wont be able to know when the date of that visit was, only the number of times they visited.

Comment: Performance wise, you can get about 4 or 5 million rows in a single table if it's indexed properly with no issues.  I have a table with 70 million rows... for example, but my server has 48gigs of ram :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are maintaining details of every visit, like treatment, prescription and other details use new log every time. otherwise increment value for each visit. second one will have best performance